# Why the current measured form the microcontroller(Stm64 Nucleo L433RC- LPSleep mode) differ from the current value written in the datasheet?

Tags: microcontroller, nucleo, st

I am using STM32L433RC -p microcontroller for current measurement. The current in the microcontroller  is measured using X Nucleo LPM01A module.I was doing a current measurement for Low Power Mode (Low Power Sleep Mode).

The current value given in the datasheet is in the range of microampere but the value which i read form the microcontroller is in the the range of milliampere.

Actually I tried both ways, by configuring myself and also from the examples provided in the CubeMx Software. In both cases current measurement was in the range of milliampere.

Can anyone provide suggestions, what can be the possible reasons for the variation in current?

Comment: You are probably measuring it wrong, or the rest of your board uses more power than you think. How are you measuring, and what else is attached?

Comment: Also, how is the current draw specified? Sometimes its uA/MHz.

Comment: @1: I am measuring using a module (X Nucleo LPM01A)

Comment: How are you configuring the pins? Did you follow the [datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32l433rc.pdf) in 6.3.5? Did you disable all the peripherals? Did you turn the clock down? Did you change the flash wait states?

Comment: @R.Joshi: It is specified in microamps.  According low power sleep mode,I have reduced the frequency  to below 2MHz . In data Sheet L433xx ,Table.41

Comment: @RonBeyer: Yeah , I  tried the same , also the example form Cube MX in repository. Still my current measured is in the range of milliamperes